# Making sense of word problem

Tags: algorithms, induction

> Suppose you begin with a pile of $n$ stones and split this pile into
>   $n$ piles of one stone each by successively splitting a pile of stones
>   into two smaller piles. Each time you split a pile you multiply the
>   number of stones in each of the two smaller piles you form, so that if
>   these piles have $r$ and $s$ stones in them, respectively, you compute
>   $rs$. Show, by strong induction, that no matter how you split the
>   piles, the sum of the products computed at each step equals
>   $n(n-1)/2$.

I'm not sure how to make sense of this question. Am I supposed to prove that $\Sigma rs = n(n-1)/2$? What of instances where $n \% 2 = 1$? I can't split 3 stones into piles $r$ and $s$ of equal size.

PS: I don't want the answer, I just can't comprehend how to begin.

Comment: The question doesn't say that $r=s$; the piles don't have to be of equal size, they just have to be smaller than the original pile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Strong Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) you use will probably be on $n$, the number of stones you start with.

You will be assuming that the statement is true for all values of $n$ less than, let's say, $m+1$. This means when you have $k$ stones so that $1 \leq k \leq m$ the sum of the $rs$ values, for all of the split piles, is $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$.

Then you should be able to prove that the sum of the $rs$ values when you start with $m+1$ stones is $$\displaystyle\sum rs = \frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$$

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure what "strong induction" means, but the obvious approach is to assume the result holds for $n \lt N$, so then if we have $N$ stones and make a first split into piles with $r$ and $s$ stones, then the total, for any method of continuing to total splitting, will be just:
$$
rs + \frac12 r(r-1) + \frac12 s(s-1)
$$
a little algebra then shows that this evaluates to $\frac12 N(N-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to prove that $$\sum rs = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ where the sum is taken over all the products $rs$ that you get while splitting the stones. It is not required to split the stones in equal piles.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of the play of the game might be helpful.

**Examples:** Suppose that $n=4$. The game could play out in either of the following ways, with the appropriate product $rs$ written over each arrow:

$$\begin{align*}
&4\overset{3}\longrightarrow3,1\overset{2}\longrightarrow2,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1\\
&4\overset{4}\longrightarrow2,2\overset{1}\longrightarrow2,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1
\end{align*}$$

In each case the total is $6$.

For $n=5$:

$$\begin{align*}
&5\overset{6}\longrightarrow3,2\overset{1}\longrightarrow3,1,1\overset{2}\longrightarrow2,1,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1,1\\
&5\overset{6}\longrightarrow3,2\overset{2}\longrightarrow2,1,2\overset{1}\longrightarrow2,1,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1,1\\
&5\overset{4}\longrightarrow4,1\overset{3}\longrightarrow3,1,1\overset{2}\longrightarrow2,1,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1,1\\
&5\overset{4}\longrightarrow4,1\overset{4}\longrightarrow2,2,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow2,1,1,1\overset{1}\longrightarrow1,1,1,1,1\\
\end{align*}$$

In each case the total is $10$.

By the way, a nice exercise is to show that the game always takes exactly $n-1$ steps. HINT: Look at the number of piles after each step.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep taking 1 stone off n, you find that the product is n-1+n-2+...which is obviously $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. You have to figure that eventually, all divisions will give the same result. As a starter, all piles will eventually have to have a 1-1 split. That mean they must eventually have a split with a pile of 2. And so on.